# good automation testing tool based on python's unittest

Tags: python

I'm looking for a good open sourced automation testing tool using python's unittest, which can
be followed as a "formal pattern" of writing a similar tool.

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't integrated it into my own personal workflow, I know of quite a number of developers who swear by [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/views/hudson-tutorials). Source is available on [Github](https://github.com/jenkinsci).